# How to change the user type in Joomla through SQL?

Tags: sql, joomla

Can anyone tell me how i can change a users type from 'Registered' to 'Super Administrator' using SQL or phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the table "jos_users" and change the field values "usertype" to "Super Administrator" and "gid" to "25".and also note down your user id.

And go to table "jos_core_acl_aro" and check ur uesrid with the "value" field and note down that id (that is "jos_core_acl_aro" id).

Then,
go to table "jos_core_acl_groups_aro_map" and change the "group_id" value to "25" matching the "aro_id" with the 
jos_core_acl_aro" id (that is "aro_id" is equal to jos_core_acl_aro" id)

Comment: Of course this will only work in Joomla 1.5 or earlier where these tables exist.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you never changed the user groups after you installed Super Users would be group 8.  You can see this in the usergroups table.

Go to the user_usergroup_map table and change the group for your user to 8.

Comment: Thanks! This worked: update XXX_user_usergroup_map set group_id = 8 where user_id = XX;